# A proof of why $y=mx$ grows faster than $y=\ln x$ for all $m \not = 0$

Tags: limits, functions

Akin to the title, how do I prove that the linear function $y=mx$  grows faster than the logarithmic function? (It was easy to show graphically for a few examples but is there a more rigorous proof?)

Comment: Just divide the first by the second and calculate the limit

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Looking at the derivatives, $m>\frac1x$ eventually

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could prove as follows:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{mx}{\ln(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{mx}{2\ln(\sqrt{x})} \ge \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{mx}{2\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{m\sqrt{x}}{2}=\infty, (m\not = 0)$$
which takes advantage of $\ln(x) < \sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 1):

To prove this, consider the limit:
$$ L=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{mx}{\ln x} $$
$(m > 0$). Using, for instance, L'Hospital's rule, you can easily see that:
$$ L= \infty$$
This means that $f(x)=mx$ grows faster than $g(x)=\ln x$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof, is there a different way to solve it besides limits?

Comment: There are various methods to prove it. For instance, you can use derivatives (which however still involve limits by definition), as suggested by @J.W.Tanner. See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511234/how-do-i-prove-that-a-function-grows-faster-than-another#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=There%20are%20many%20ways.,the%20ratio%20grows%20without%20bound for something more on this,

Comment: @Miko If you mean the proof besides anything that is related to limits (even derivatives), then it's almost impossible (unless you accept the graph proof).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence

$$\frac{mx}{\log x}=\frac{me^n}n.$$

We have
$$\frac{\dfrac{me^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\dfrac{me^n}n}=\frac{en}{n+1}\ge\frac e2>1$$ so that the sequence grows as fast as a geometric one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>0$. Observe that
$$
e^x  = 1 + x + \frac{{x^2 }}{2} +  \cdots  > 1 + x > x.
$$
Taking logarithms and using that the $\log$ is monotonically increasing, we obtain
$$
\log x < x.
$$
Thus,
$$
\log x = 2\frac{1}{2}\log x = 2\log \sqrt x  < 2\sqrt x 
$$
for any $x>0$. Finally, if $m>0$,
$$
\frac{{mx}}{{\log x}} > \frac{{mx}}{{2\sqrt x }} = \frac{m}{2}\sqrt x ,
$$
showing the desired result.